# About WLUA.exe no-console binary

Tags: windows, lua

friend.
This question goes for RBerteig or some that can help me.

You have answer to another colleague about WLuaJit.exe "which is windowless". This was your answer:

*The only difference between **wlua.exe** and **lua.exe** is that the former has **subsystem:windows** rather than **subsystem:console** specified at link time. As a result Windows chooses to not automatically associate it with a console, and does not create a console window to associate it to. When you decide you need your own distinct **.exe** file to hold up a private icon and other branding resources, you can easily do the same thing. I've often found it handy to keep a console build around for debugging even when shipping a GUI. – RBerteig Nov 25 '13 at 23:30*

Then sorry, I do not know enough of C/C++ language for doing that. Can you guide me for doing the adjustments to the MakeFile (I think that is the way) for me myself do the changes and build/compile it?

Thanks.

**HERNAN CANO M**

Systems Analyst

Medellín, Antioquia, Colombia

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question.

Comment: Probably, @RBerteig was talking about the following sequence of functions: `AllocConsole(); WriteConsole(...); ReadConsole(...); FreeConsole();`

Comment: Thanks, cartant. Sorry, I'm new... but I respect rules. After reading your link I keep on considering my question is

Comment: ...Ok.. I would like you clarify me. By.

Comment: Yes, Egor. May be... but any way I do not know enough of C/C++. Thanks for trying to help me.